Is it possible to display a pop-up window when entering a specific component?
I am creating a simple web page using React.
I need one feature, but I'm wondering if it's possible in React.
The function I want is not to open a pop-up window by directly onClick,
Can a component connected to a specific URL automatically display a pop-up?
const myComponent = () => {
  return (
    window.open(
      <div>display</div>
    )
  )
}

export default myComponent

The code I want is roughly like this.
Is this possible in React?

if you want something to trigger only once when a component is rendered, you call a "useEffect" hook with an empty dependency array.  for example:  useEffect(() => { window.open(display) }, []);  the array is what tells the hook to run again if an item in it changes.  so if it is empty, it will only run once.
